# How do I decrease pip install size for a docker image?

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile

I'm quite new to docker but I'm really hungry for optimizations.

Previously my project's docker image used to be **~13GB** and used to take **~7-10 minutes** to build and **~7 mins** to push.

Here are the improvements I made:

1. Copying just requirements before the pip installs (so code change doesn't trigger pip installs. That used to happen every time). Brought down build times to **30 secs**, and push time to **10 secs**.
2. Used the option **--no-cache-dir** for pip installs. This removes the setup files like whls etc, AFAIK. Then the image size got down to **~7GB**.

Running docker image history myimage:mytag gave me sizes after each layer in Dockerfile.

**Question:**

My pip install requirements.txt still has a lion's share of volume at **4.7GB**. How do I reduce it???

One thought that comes to mind is using the **--no-deps** option for pip installs. No idea if that'd work out as intended. The code has been a collaboration, so I'm not fully aware if any dependencies are being used or not.

Is there any other way to reduce size? Or an elegant way to use --no-deps?

Edit: [Adding link to Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/q9oajr/on_a_mission_to_optimize_my_docker_image/) question where I have more info, like my DOcker file, breakup of sizes, etc.

Comment: What does your requirements.txt contain to install 4.7GB of packages?

Comment: I am downvoting on the basis that not enough info is provided. Your project requirements might be close to 5GB, but without details on what those requirements are and why they are needed, likely it’s not enough info by itself.

Comment: @rv.kvetch added a link in the end of my post to my Reddit question where I have more info.

Comment: Yes, but i still don't see what the requirements are in that reddit post. I don't understand what is the need to be so secretive about a requirements.txt file; after all, I assume they are public pypi dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

One option you have  is to set up [multi-stage Docker builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds) for you application to produce separate images as they’re used in development, staging, and production environments — with the requirements tailored to each.